# Android : Unable to cancel alarm using AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

This is what I am using to set a alarm and it is visible when I fetch all the alarms set in the device.

```
    /**
     * Set alarm
     **/


    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, LocalReminderReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long time = Long.valueOf("1526112720000");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, alarmIntent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);

    /**
     * Cancel alarm
     */
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    sender.cancel();
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To set alarm use below line**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);

 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID, intent, 0);

 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
 am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

**To Cancel alarm use below line**

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,requestID, intent, 0);
 am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Above both code for set and cancel alram is working for me.
You have to just pass same **request id** to set and cancel particular alarm

Comment: Need to use PendingIntent.getBroadcast instead of PendingIntent.getActivity, if one wants to use Broadcast Receiver